# How to get the SQL Server script error in a batch File

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, error-handling, sql-scripts

I am calling an SQL Server script on a batch file, but I need get the error(when the script fail) in the batch file, what can I do?

This is the batch file:

```
sqlcmd -S HOST  -U User -P password -i test.sql
echo %errorlevel%
```

and this is the Script File(Test.sql):

```
USE TrainingSitecore_Web  
go

SELECT * FROM   items 
go

RAISERROR ('This is a test Error.',-- Message text.
           16,-- Severity.
           1 -- State.
);
```

Make sense?

Comment: Will the last answer in the below link is your case? 
http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/77298/how-to-make-sqlcmd-return-an-errorlevel-other-than-0-when-the-sql-script-fails

Comment: Yes men, it is working :)

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using -r parameter:

Example:

```
sqlcmd -Q "select 1 as a; select 1/0 as b" -E -r1 1> NUL
```

> -r[ 0 | 1] msgs to stderr
>
> Redirects the error message output to the screen (stderr). If you do
>   not specify a parameter or if you specify 0, only error messages that
>   have a severity level of 11 or higher are redirected. If you specify
>   1, all error message output including PRINT is redirected. Has no
>   effect if you use -o. By default, messages are sent to stdout.

[MSDN for more](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks but not work, the error level still in 0 :(, look at http://postimg.org/image/95wwn7p3z/